# What does each column tag attribute represent?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I see that the grid columns in Magento 2 that are declared via ui-components support the following tags:

- name - identifier of the column
- class - class used for preparing the data displayed in the column
- disabled - can be used to disable a grid column
- dataSource - ?
- layout - ?

As shown above, I (think I) know what 3 out of 5 attributes do and mean.
What do the `dataSource` and `layout` attributes do and mean?